# Javascript set variable value in string

Tags: javascript

```
var f = "world!";
var b = `hello  ${f}`;
```

> b now == hello world!

I want function like this below set all value to string variable I know this function its fail and will give `undefined f`

Why i need this function... I will pass some data from PHP and I want in Javascript save this data

AND

Render some HTML with this data

```
var p =`hello ${f}`;
var b = 'world!';

function render(x,f){
console.log(x);
}


render(p,b);
```

Any ideas for function like this

Comment: A plugin that somewhat does what you're after: https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible because of how JS works.

In theory, templates are very powerful in JS and you can use tagged templates and get really nifty stuff. However, in your case you want to not error in the case `f` is not defined.

The reference of `f` is evaluated *before* the function is - and when an unknown identifier is found JavaScript will throw a `ReferenceError`.

You can use a regular templating engine like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) though or use a simple helper function and a regex - just not with backtick template syntax.

Alternatively, pass a *function* in like:

```
var p = o => `hello ${o.f}`;
var b = 'world!';

function render(x,f){
    console.log(x({f}));
}
```

Or if you're *really* noughty, `with` and dynamic scoping can let you omit the `o.` before properties like libraries like KnockoutJS do.

Comment: MDN reference for the second bit?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings